# How to Load Script using script manager, but some script before UI load and some After

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am facing a problem in asp.net,
I want to load some script before UI load and some after Ui load.
but as we can use single script manager in a page and so we can use LOadbeforeUi property of script manager single time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338357.aspx) will be added at the beginning of the page so it will be executed before DOM is fully loaded.

[`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408.aspx) will be added after the page content so it will be executed after DOM is parsed.

Comment: Is there any way to do this by using ScriptManagerProxy??